# Linkify TextView

Tags: android

i have listview and i call intent from the listview onitem selected method

but when i get linkfy textview in my listrow than i am not able to call intent from the onItem selected method.

Any suggestion would be helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little short on detail here, but it sounds like you want your text to look like a link while still using the list view's onListItemSelected method to handle clicking on the link.

I haven't used 'linkify' in a textview before but I suspect it might be overriding the click/touch event that the list would otherwise be using (to act as a link instead).

If you still want it to look like a link while using the onListItemSelected method, you could easily modify the textview's text color to blue instead, though underlining the text might be a bit more difficult to achieve.